# RSA host key for IP address 'XX.XX.XX.XX' not in list of known hosts

Tags: linux, rsa

Im getting the error RSA host key of the git repository not in the list of known hosts. when i run my jenkins job with repository URL as my git clone URL.

I have tried cloning the same repository in the host on which i'm running the job . It clones without any issue.

My ssh key of the host is already added to the git repo.

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/local/packages/git-2.9.2/bin/git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master --prune" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: FIPS integrity verification test failed.
RSA host key for IP address 'XX.XX.XX.XX' not in list of known hosts.
Permission denied (keyboard-interactive,publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in on the machine as the jenkins user, try to do it manually. You probably get a message saying that the fingerprint for that host is unknown and the question if you want to trust it. If you choose yes, the next build you'll trigger should work.